# Excel SUMIF, sum another cell if empty

Tags: excel

I would like the total sum of Col A but if the cell of Col A is empty, take Col B

[image: Table]

So this example sum would be 185

I tried SUMIF with various parameters but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can Use this:**

```
=SUM(B2:B4) + SUMIF(B2:B4, "", C2:C4)
```

**And for a structured reference (Table Header) use this:**

Table1: is name of the table

```
=SUM(Table1[Col A]) + SUMIF(Table1[Col A], "", Table1[Col B])
```

SUMIF function has many parameter:

```
SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])
```

here, the criteria is applied the same values that are being summed. If you want, you can apply the criteria to one range and sum the corresponding values in a different range.

*For example, the formula =SUMIF(B2:B4, "", C2:C4) sums only the values in the range C2:C4, where the corresponding cells in the range B2:B4 equal "".*

From Excel Help.

[image: Sum of table column]

Comment: Great answer.  May be better to make the answer refer to the columns A and B (as per OP's question), but otherwise great stuff - works like a charm

Comment: Yes, this is a better answer than mine :-) I guess mine would work for other things than "" in column A, but that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can only come up with an array formula like

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A:A),A:A,B:B))
```

(must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>)